# Display Categories as top nav menu in magento

Tags: magento

Hii i am a newbie in magento. I have created a root category called 'computer' and added two subcategories namely - mouse and HDD to it . I want to display the root category in the header section as - Computer and then on mouse over the sub categories Mouse,HDD will show and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place your top level categories directly below a root category for them to be shown.

The screenshot below shows a Root category (which is not visible on the frontend) with 4 top level categories listed directly below.  It is these that will/can be visible in the main navigation.

[image]

Also, ensure that the category is active and that "Include in Navigation Menu" is set to "Yes".  This can be found towards the bottom of the "General Information" tab in the category settings.

Finally, make sure that the root category you are using is assigned to the correct store: `System > Manage Stores`

Comment: do i have add any piece of code ? i just created a root category and added 2 sub categories under it..

Comment: my navigation is just the same as you have but with two root categories 1)Computer and 2)Furniture. Its Not showing in the header section. 
This is my magento website:-
http://173.192.186.220/~newmedia/dev/magento/index.php/?dir=asc&order=name

Comment: If you have only 1 store then you require only 1 root category. You need to create a single root category and move your category structure below this.  Then go to configuration > system > manage stores and select your store.  Make sure the correct root category is selected.

Comment: its giving a 404 error: Page not found.when i edited the store. no page is opening now.

Comment: Please make sure you have followed these instructions correctly: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/creating_and_assigning_root_categories